# Refreshing datatable with json data in razor views without reloading page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, datatable, asp.net-ajax

Am using a datatable from following link.. https://datatables.net/.

On loading a view for the first time i load/draw the table with a model data in my ASP MVC5 project.

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="min-width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>ItemDesc</th>
            <th>UM</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
            <td>item.Item</td>
            <td>item.ItemDesc</td>
            <td>item.UM</td>
            <td>item.Qty</th>
            <td>item.Category</td>
            <td>item.Comment</td>
            <td>item.Delete</td>
            </tr>
         }
```

I edit the data on screen with a modal popup and save to db.After closing the pop i need to refresh the datatable with ajax-json data.How to refresh the existing table without reloading page? 
i have done some work around with following ;but nothing helped-
[https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url())
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url()

Comment: after editing your data then just refresh your window so that data inside datatable could also be refreshed..

Comment: are you talking about refreshing the page??!!.. i have a data-object ready to be bind with datatable but don't know how to do it!!

Comment: yes i m saying that just refresh the page..with.window.location.reload()....

Comment: that works.. but it refreshes the page.. i need to bind new data to datatable!

Comment: @flute..i have never used datatable so what i can suggest i just told to you..thankzz....